# IOS objective-C UIAlertView Bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, dealloc

This is my method:

```
- (void)showAlertMsgWithKey: (NSString *)key Title: (NSString *)title CancelBtnTitle: (NSString *)cancelBtnTitle{

    static int counter = 0;

    UIAlertView *alertMsg = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: title
                                                       message: [[MessageDictionary sharedInstance].msg objectForKey: key]
                                                      delegate: self
                                             cancelButtonTitle: cancelBtnTitle
                                             otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [maAlert addObject: alertMsg];

    [[maAlert objectAtIndex: counter] show];

    counter++;
```

}

then I try to show two alert view that stack up over on another by calling this method twice

```
[super showAlertMsgWithKey:@"10000" Title:@"testing" CancelBtnTitle:@"OK"];
[super showAlertMsgWithKey:@"10001" Title:@"testing1" CancelBtnTitle:@"OOKK"];
```

but in the end the compiler show me this error:

```
Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is
deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behaviour
(<UIAlertController: 0x7fd669f591c0>)
```

Comment: why are you calling the showAlert method on super ? YOu should be calling it using self.

Comment: Stop using alert view, use Alert Controller.

Comment: it's not a bug: error description is telling you what you are doing wrong. you might want to present it from `appDelegate.window.rootViewController`. And also listen to Mr.UB... And it's not the compiler showing you that message, is it? This can only happen during runtime...

Comment: @TejaNandamuri becuz i doing in inheritance concept

Comment: @rokjarc if using alert controller can solve the problem or any solution for this?

Comment: @Shank1: no, but `UIAlertView` is deprecated hence not to be used in new applications. As for the question: it seems you are showing it from a viewController that is being deallocated: which is wrong. I tend to present alerts from the `rootViewController`: it really depends on your view architecture.

Comment: I was solved it by maAlert = [NSMutableArray new]; haha i was forget to allocate memory for the array oops